# How to correctly exclude records when tables are connected with one to many relationship

Tags: sql, performance, one-to-many, not-exists

**Overview:** I am working with two tables that are connected with one-to-many relationship
(i.e. one record from Contacts table can have many rows / records in CustomerExclusion table

| **Contacts** |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerID | CustomerName | Country |
| 1 | Alfreds Futterkiste | Germany |
| 2 | Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados | Mexico |
| 3 | Antonio Moreno Taquería | Mexico |
| 4 | Around the Horn | UK |
| 5 | Berglunds snabbköp | Sweden |
| 6 | Blauer See Delikatessen | Germany |
| 7 | Blondel père et fils | France |
| 8 | Bólido Comidas preparadas | Spain |
| 9 | John | Germany |

| **CustomerExclusion** |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CustomerID | exclusion_type | Flag |
| 1 | BadAddress | Y |
| 1 | Optout | Y |
| 3 | NoCall | Y |
| 4 | BadEmail | Y |
| 5 | BadAddress | Y |
| 6 | BadAddress | Y |
| 6 | Optout | Y |
| 9 | BadAddress | N |

**Desired output:** I want records from Contacts table AFTER excluding records with exclusion_type = 'BadAddress' or 'OptOutOnly' (any one  OR BOTH) and flag = 'Y' for each exclusion_type

**Questions:** So far, I have tried 3 different approach (1 & 2 are giving me desired output while 3 is not).

- Which one is the correct approach?
- What is the difference in each approach?
- In terms of optimization (better speed), which one is better approach?

**Approach 1:**

```
select c.* from Contacts c
WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM CustomerExclusion e
        WHERE e.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
            AND e.exclusion_type IN ('BadAddress','OptOutOnly') and e.flag = 'Y'
    )
```

**Approach 2:**

```
select c.* from Contacts c
WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT CustomerID
        FROM CustomerExclusion e
        WHERE e.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        AND e.exclusion_type IN ('BadAddress','OptOutOnly') and e.flag = 'Y'
    )
```

**Approach 3:**

```
select c.* from Contacts c
WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT CustomerID
        FROM CustomerExclusion e
        WHERE e.exclusion_type IN ('BadAddress','OptOutOnly') and e.flag = 'Y'
    )
```

Comment: approach 3 will not work as there's no coorlation between the queries.  Options 1 and two are nearly identical the only difference being the 1 and customer ID in the select of the coorlated query.  and it doesn't matter what gets selected.  The 1 is slighly more performant as the system doesn't have the overhead of resolving each of those values.  So approach 1 is the correct approach in my book

Comment: 1) if it gives the correct answer then it is a correct approach. Under most circumstances there is no such thing as the correct approach 2) When you run the queries which one is faster? That’s the more optimised one for you. Speed is dependent on lots of variables that will be specific to your circumstances - so anyone else is really just giving an opinion/guessing

Comment: Thank you @xQbert exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you @NickW as well. For performance, my goal is to simply learn / understand how the query structure impacts the performance (NOT accounting for other variables that are outside my control). My question is focused on query since that is the only thing under my control (NOT accounting for any hardware or database which I am sure impacts but that's outside the scope of this discussion).

Comment: An alternative approach would be an inner join between the tables but the not exists is likely more performant; though that will depend on indexes; table statistics (record count, size etc)  and from a design stand point a join (in my opinion) should only be executed if you need records/columns returned in your result set from the table

Comment: Hi @xQbert One question. when we select 1 VERSUS the fieldname (in my case  customerID); does that mean in both options, we are selecting ALL records? OR in selecting 1, we only care about 1 match since we are excluding in this case?

Comment: Neither.  It simply means return the value of 1 for all records returned  in the query, which then never gets used. since the correlation (your were clause `e.CustomerID = c.CustomerID`) between it and the main query is what limits the records being returned in your main query.  That's why there is a small gain the "Selected" value is never used in the sub query. so why return any value or force the engine to do more work; provide the engine  a constant and it's that value for all records.  The engine doesn't have to look up each record value and thus an unused 1 is returned for all records.

Comment: ah got it, this makes sense. I am glad I asked this question (now I know0. Thank you so much @xQbert

Comment: Seek first to undertstand.  From understanding comes knowledge and tolerance.

Comment: FYI, using `select col_x` or `select 1` or `select *` or `select null` when using exists. It really does not matter, any of those would work equally. The "existence" of a row is determined through the FROM & WHERE clauses.  Existence is NOT determined by comparing that data selected in that clause. In effect the select clause is really only there because a syntax rule requires select as the first clause.